# Inherited XmlTextWriter with XmlWriterSettings

Tags: c#, .net, xml, inheritance, xmlwriter

There are quite a few questions related to this topic that I have browsed through.

But it seems that I have a unique case where we are inheriting a class from XmlTextWriter which makes it impossible to use the XmlWriter.Create() method for instantiating an XmlWriter with XmlWriterSettings.

So the question - Is there a way to specify XmlWriterSettings like OmitXmlDeclaration, DoNotEscapeUriAttributes and CloseOutput for the inherited instance ?

Note: I have used Formatting property in the inherited class but could not locate above mentioned properties unless set through XmlWriterSettings.

Comment: No.  E.g. for `CloseOutput`,If you look at the [reference source for `XmlTextWriter.Close()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextWriter.cs,839) the underlying text writer is closed unconditionally.  Compare with [`XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.Close()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.cs,587) where the underlying writer is conditionally closed.

Comment: Have you considered using the decorator pattern to wrap the writer returned from `XmlWriter.Create()` in a decorator, for instance as is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42960980) to [How can I stop empty XML elements self-closing using XmlDocument in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42959958)?

Comment: But for `CloseOutput` you could always construct a `StreamWriter` that does not close the underlying stream, using one of the answers from [Is there any way to close a StreamWriter without closing its BaseStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2666888).

Comment: @dbc Thanks for the links and the answer below. Will check it out.

Comment: Would like to know why the question was downvoted.

Comment: Thanks @dbc.

Would the person who has downvoted please mention the reason for doing so ?

Answer (score 1):

`XmlTextWriter` does not support all the options available in `XmlWriterSettings`.  The class was originally created for writing XML in .Net 1.x and was deprecated in favor of `XmlWriter.Create()` in .Net 2.0, as explained in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, we recommend that you use the System.Xml.XmlWriter class instead.

Full support for `XmlWriterSettings` was never added to the old `XmlTextWriter` and vice versa.  This can be confirmed by checking the reference source.

For instance, for `CloseOutput`, if you look at the [reference source for `XmlTextWriter.Close()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextWriter.cs,839) the underlying text writer is closed unconditionally:

```
    public override void Close() {
        try {
            AutoCompleteAll();
        } 
        catch { // never fail
        } 
        finally {
            this.currentState = State.Closed;
            textWriter.Close();
        }
    }
```

Compare with [`XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.Close()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.cs,587) (this class is one of the XML writers returned by `XmlWriter.Create()`) where the underlying text writer is conditionally closed:

```
    public override void Close() {
        try {
            FlushBuffer();
            FlushEncoder();
        }
        finally {
            // Future calls to Close or Flush shouldn't write to Stream or Writer
            writeToNull = true;

            if ( stream != null ) {
                try {
                    stream.Flush();
                }
                finally {
                    try {
                        if ( closeOutput ) {
                            stream.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    finally {
                        stream = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

(However, you could always construct a `StreamWriter` that does not close the underlying stream, using one of the answers from [Is there any way to close a StreamWriter without closing its BaseStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2666888).)

Similarly [`XmlTextWriter.WriteStartDocument()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextWriter.cs,351) does not appear to have an option to not emit an XML declaration:

```
    public override void WriteStartDocument() {
        StartDocument(-1);
    }

    // Writes out the XML declaration with the version "1.0" and the standalone attribute.
    public override void WriteStartDocument(bool standalone) {
        StartDocument(standalone ? 1 : 0);
    }

    void StartDocument(int standalone) {
        try {
            if (this.currentState != State.Start) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(Res.GetString(Res.Xml_NotTheFirst));
            }
            this.stateTable = stateTableDocument;
            this.currentState = State.Prolog;

            StringBuilder bufBld = new StringBuilder(128);
            bufBld.Append("version=" + quoteChar + "1.0" + quoteChar);
            if (this.encoding != null) {
                bufBld.Append(" encoding=");
                bufBld.Append(quoteChar);
                bufBld.Append(this.encoding.WebName);
                bufBld.Append(quoteChar);
            }
            if (standalone >= 0) {
                bufBld.Append(" standalone=");
                bufBld.Append(quoteChar);
                bufBld.Append(standalone == 0 ? "no" : "yes");
                bufBld.Append(quoteChar);
            }
            InternalWriteProcessingInstruction("xml", bufBld.ToString());
        }
        catch {
            currentState = State.Error;
            throw;
        }
    }

    void InternalWriteProcessingInstruction(string name, string text) {
        textWriter.Write("<?");
        ValidateName(name, false);
        textWriter.Write(name);
        textWriter.Write(' ');
        if (null != text) {
            xmlEncoder.WriteRawWithSurrogateChecking(text);
        }
        textWriter.Write("?>");
    }
```

It would seem `StartDocument()` must needs be called to initialize the writer's internal state, but when called, an XML declaration is always written.

As an alternative, have you considered using the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and wrapping the writer returned from `XmlWriter.Create()` in a decorator, e.g. as is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42960980) to [How can I stop empty XML elements self-closing using XmlDocument in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42959958)?  This would allow you to customize your output before passing it to the underlying `XmlWriter` similarly to how your subclass of `XmlTextWriter` could customize the output before passing to the base class's methods.