# DataSet.Writexml returning empty tag

Tags: c#, xml

I have a dataset with a column "awe_cust" when this column is empty dataset.Writexml returns <awe_cust />. I need it to return <awe_cust></awe_cust>. is this possible?

Comment: The xml specification allows both formats.  The Net library saves character and does not add the tag name to a closing tag when it is empty.

Comment: I understand that both formats are within xml specs. I have a requirement for a project were it must be formatted as described.

Comment: Since `<awe_cust />` and `<awe_cust></awe_cust>` are semantically identical, the decision to use one form or the other is made by `XmlWriter` not `DataSet`. ...

Comment: To force the full element to be written by the writer, grab `FullElementXmlTextWriter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42960980/3744182) to [How can I stop empty XML elements self-closing using XmlDocument in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42959958/3744182) and pass it to [`DataSet.WriteXml(XmlWriter)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.writexml?view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataSet_WriteXml_System_Xml_XmlWriter_).  In fact this looks to be a duplicate of that question, agree?